# Fetch All Upcoming Facebook Friends Birthdays, not only for Current Year

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am writing an **Android Facebook App**, in which i am trying to fetch *list of all upcoming facebook friends birthdays*, and i am able to fetch that.

But i am facing a problem, i am only fetching list of **friends till end of december** for this year, **not all upcoming** *like today is March 15, so i want to fetch list of facebook friends those birthdays come within today to March 14, but i am getting today to December 31*

See below **code** and help me to resolve this small issue:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date today = cal.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
    String today_formatted = formatter.format(today);
    String query = "select name, birthday, uid, pic_square FROM user " +
    "WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND birthday_date != 'null' " +
    "AND birthday_date >= '" + today_formatted + "'ORDER BY birthday_date ASC";
```